# Container is exiting on its own & not able to exec into it

Tags: docker, selenium, dockerfile, selenium-docker

I am trying to build and container image & then trying to run the enter the container after running it. But I am getting error response from daemon.

My Docker file -

```
COPY . /app
RUN sudo chmod 777 -R /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD entry_point.sh /opt/bin/
RUN sudo chmod 777 /opt/bin/entry_point.sh
COPY start-selenium-standalone.sh /opt/bin/start-selenium-standalone.sh
RUN sudo chmod 777 /opt/bin/start-selenium-standalone.sh
EXPOSE 4444 5900 9515

**Command to build docker image**
docker build -f Docker/Dockerfile -t sel-test:1 .

**Command to run the image** 
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm sel-test:1

**Error I am getting -**
Error response from daemon: Container a9e0bb7f381584dd5e39dcd997640233835408ffdfe4e0e44108ddb7bb393cd0 is not running
```

Comment: You obviously miss a CMD. Turn your RUN into it

Answer (score 0):

Your container is exiting because there is nothing to run inside the container.

To see this, run the `docker ps -a` command and check the status of your container.

In order to run something inside the container use `CMD` in docker file to run bash inside the container whenever you use 'docker run'.